# How do i make the module 'requests' click a button in python

Tags: python, python-requests, web-development-server

Would I need to do use post to make it click a button, I have tried using get to do it and it gives me a status code of 200 but doesn't run the file.

Comment: What happens normally when you click button? Find that out first. Then copy it using requests as you wanted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.